# Substring after a pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, substring

I have a string:

```
str = word1.woa.1398 word2.woa.1398 word3.woa.1398 word4.woa.1398 word5.woa.1398
```

I want to extract "1398" for word3. I need the value of path to be just "1398". When I use:

```
path = str[/(?:word3.woa.*)[0-9]+/]
```

I get:

```
"word3.woa.1398 word4.woa.1398 word5.woa.1398"
```

Can someone provide me the correct regex?

Comment: Check out rubular.com

Comment: Reading "[ask]", "[mcve]", "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)", Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)" would be useful. Your `str` definition doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
> s = "word1.woa.1398 word2.woa.1398 word3.woa.1398 word4.woa.1398 word5.woa.1398"
> s.match(/word3.woa.(\d+)/).captures[0]
=> "1398"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may capture the part and get it easily using the current notation as:

```
path = str[/\bword3\.woa\.([0-9]+)/, 1]
path
# => 1398
```

Here, note that the dots are escaped to match literal dots, and the `1` means we need to extract only the contents of the first capturing group.

See the [Ruby demo online](http://rextester.com/ESGQ63788). Also, see this [**Rubular demo**](http://rubular.com/r/EOPhNbx0xe) (pay attention to *"Match groups:"* section).

Note that the pattern matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `word3\.woa\.` - a `word3.woa.` literal substring
- `([0-9]+)`  - 1 or more digits captured into Group 1.

Ruby Onigmo regex library supports `\K` (match reset operator), so you may actually just match the left-hand context, and discard it by placing `\K` right after it, and grab the 1+ digits as a plain match text, no need for lookbehinds/capturing groups:

```
path = str[/\bword3\.woa\.\K[0-9]+/]
path
# => 1398
```

See [another Ruby demo](http://rextester.com/LIBFW64625). Here, all you matched with `\bword3\.woa\.` is dropped and what is matched with `[0-9]+` lands in the resulting match value.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'word2.woa.1398 word3.woa.1398 word4.woa.1398'

str[/(?<=\sword3\.woa\.)\d+/]
  #=> "1398"
```

`(?<=\sword3\.woa\.)` is a *positive lookbehind*, requiring `\d+` to be preceded immediately by `\sword3\.woa\.`